# Can't store contacts on my Android phone

Tags: contacts

I was going through all of my installed applications on my phone a while ago, just to clear out what junk is in there I don't need. And like an idiot, I looked at my Contacts Storage (com.android.providers.contacts version 4.4.4-4c563b90c4) app and thought, "U know what, my contacts are already on my Contacts app, I don't need this." And so I cleared data and disabled the app.

I went to my Contacts app to see if everything was fine, and all my contacts were gone. Panicking, I went back to my Settings and enabled Contacts Storage back up again, and when I went back in to re-enter my contacts, an error message came up:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify both or neither of ACCOUNT_NAME and ACCOUNT_TYPE; URI: content:// com.android.contacts/raw_contacts, calling user: com.simplemobiletools.contacts, calling package:com.simplemobiletools.contacts

I don't know if a certain piece of software required to save my contacts was deleted along with my contacts. Does that mean I can't store contacts for good? I don't have a Google account saved on my phone.

I'm using an Amazon Fire Phone running CyanogenMod 11-201508100UNOFFICIAL-kodiak on Android 4.4.4

Comment: Unfortunately, you may simply need to reset the phone. It sounds extremely plausible that you did indeed delete some necessary configuration files or or other information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you wrote above, 99% you cannot restore your contact. No google account literally reduce your chance to restore contact. I am sorry.

Next time, please backup your phone. The simplest backup IMO is a google account. Your contacts, app, calendar will sync to google account. You don't have to use your personal gmail for your phone. Just create another gmail for your Amazon fire phone. How to sync your personal email and Amazon file phone gmail is another question.

Please mark as answered, i am collecting points. thanks

Comment: Thanks for your remark. Now based on my error message, does this mean that I can't even save contacts anymore? Because that's what matters to me at the most.

Comment: The simplest thing is to do factory-reset. I will restore your phone like before, and surely you can save contacts again.